# Date Range Query not returning all records - SQL

Tags: sql, date, between

I have a SQL db that I need to filter results based on the month that inventory items were completed in order to do the billing.

The field I'm working with is called CompletionDate.  Here is the code I'm using.

```
input name='criteria' type='hidden' value="WHERE CompletionDate BETWEEN '8-1-2013' AND '8-31-2013'"
```

I get some of the records returned but not all.  I suspect that the problem lies in the format of the CompletionDate field.  It is currently a varchar(10).  I am storing the data in this field in the format MM-DD-YYYY.

After some searching I understand that since the field is in a varchar datatype that the above mentioned code is not going to work the way I want it to.  I've tried this to no avail.

```
input name='criteria' type='hidden' value="WHERE to_date(CompletionDate, 'mm-dd-yyyy') BETWEEN to_date('8-1-2013', 'mm-dd-yyyy') AND to_date('8-31-2013', 'mm-dd-yyyy')"
```

Can anyone help guide me to the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the field is of type varchar, you are not searching for a date range but actually a text range. You really should store dates in a date type field, because then you can easily and efficiently do date range queries.

Your workaround using to_date should in theory work, although it is rather inefficient as the database has to try to convert the text from each row into a real date in order to be able to do the comparison. As to why it actually does not work is still unclear. What database are you using? Is the format string correct or should it be in uppercase ('MM-DD-YYYY')?

If you are stubborn in storing dates as text in the database, using a format that can be lexically sorted, e.g. YYYY-MM-DD including leading zeroes (2013-08-01), can seemingly make the range queries work. But there really are several good reasons why databases have dedicated date datatypes!

Comment: This was a bad move - going to attempt to convert the field to a date datatype.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A better way is like this:

```
where CompletionDate >= the start of your date range
and CompletionDate < the day after the end of your date range.
```

Reason number 1 is that it will take the time element into account, if applicable.
Reason number 2 is that using functions in the where clause slows down production.

By the way, if CompletionDate is a char or varchar datatype in your db, you have serious problems.

Comment: Same issue - it's omitting some results.  Yes I need to convert the field to a date datatype.  That was an oversight in my original db setup.  Thanks for your quick response